# woocommerce assign roles in registration form

Tags: woocommerce

We are building a website for our project and using Wordpress/Woocommerce.

What we want is for the registration form to allow selection of the various user types (individual, SME, etc.) or roles and then offer the appropriate pricing options depending upon the choice when a product is selected.

I've been trying to research various plugins and there are quite a few it would seem, but am new to Woocommerce and am very unsure whether they can do that exactly as required.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated,

Jim.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plugin [WP Roles at Registration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-roles-at-registration/) ,this plugin asks the user to choose his role in the website during registration from a list of selected roles.

And for pricing the products according to there roles you can use the plugins like

[Woocommerce Role Pricing](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-pricing/)

[Woocommerce Role Based Price](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-based-price/)

[WooCommerce user specific pricing extension](https://wisdmlabs.com/woocommerce-user-specific-pricing-extension/)

Check these plugins and user which fits your requirement.

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: The WP Roles at Registration plugin is not actively maintained and not compatible with the latest WordPress versions.